# How do you add another process on VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I would like to add if MyVariable is equal to 1 if will report the device is on

```
architecture sim of T06_SignalTb is
    signal MySignal : integer :=0;
    
begin
    process is
        variable MyVariable: integer :=0;  
    begin
        report "***Process begin***";
MyVariable := MyVariable + 1;
MySignal <= MySignal + 1;  
        report "MyVariable=" & integer 'image(MyVariable) & ", MySignal=" & integer 'image(MySignal);    
     MyVariable := MyVariable + 1;
    MySignal <= MySignal + 1;

        report "MyVariable=" & integer 'image(MyVariable) & ", MySignal=" & integer 'image(MySignal);
        
        Wait for 10 ns; 

        end process;
```

here is the process that i would like to add

```
process is
begin

MyVariable = 1; 
report " the device is on";

end process;
```

Comment: Your second process isn't valid VHDL. There is no declaration for MyVariable visible. The scope of a variable declaration is within the process.  Additionally you have no process sensitivity list. You evaluate MyVariable with an equality operator, but there are no sequential statements in VHDL that consist of expressions alone. (You're missing an if statement to use the evaluation as a condition.) Processes communicate with signals. Shared variables as values other than of a protected type were deprecated in -2002 and protected types don't synthesize.

Answer (score 0):

You add another process by adding the code for your second process somewhere between `begin` and `end architecture;`. They will execute concurrently. However...

Variables in VHDL are only in scope within a single process. Notice that you declared `MyVariable` within (the so-called *declarative region* of) a single process.

This is for a very good reason. If a variable were to be in scope inside some other process, your code could be non-deterministic. (It is possible to do this in Verilog and consequently it is possible to write non-deterministic code in Verilog.)

So, you will not be able to use the variable `MyVariable` in your second process if you have declared it in the first process. So, what do do?

i) use a *signal* instead. Signals are VHDL constructs whose purpose is to allow separate processes to communicate.

ii) Or write the code in one process instead of two.

iii) Or use a special kind of VHDL variable called a *shared variable*, which you would declare in the same place as a signal. However, shared variables are tricky things. They have to be of a special type called a *protected type* and if you use them, you code can be non-deterministic (just like Verilog). I would be very surprised if this were the right solution for you.

---

BTW: this code

```
MySignal <= MySignal + 1;
report "MyVariable=" & integer 'image(MyVariable) & ", MySignal=" & integer 'image(MySignal);
```

suggests that you have forgotten that signals are not updated (ie don't get their new values) until all the processes suspend (ie finish executing).

---

**Use variables to store information within a process; use signals to send information to another process.**

Comment: shared variables in VHDL 1993 can be any normal type because protected types do no exist. A lot of simulators allow "legacy" shared variables in later versions with some relaxed settings (which is default in some simulators).

Comment: [UG901](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2020_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) (Vivado, Synthesis) shows a -1993 shared variable in a RAM RTL description on page 125. Note the two processes could be combined into one and a variable declared without the shared reserved word could as easily be used. Usage is to separate reads from writes which can also be done in separate if statements in a single process. Variables simplify simulation and require less memory. Relying on a lack of standard compliance affects portability and can't be used in a multithreaded simulator.